# How to use the correct css in apps like windows live mail?

Tags: css, email, styling, newsletter

It seems that my css is not working on windows live mail and the outlook app for example i tried changing the background color for a table but it is not working for some reason. I have tried a lot of things like bgcolor, background color etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a cross-compatible CSS e-mail is no easy task...
Sadly, all the standard efforts done on the WWW didn't reach most the e-mail clients (Microsoft is not even consistent between all versions of Outlook).

Here are some tips what work most of the time :

- use **HTML table** to do the layout
- use **HTML 4** tags and attributes instead of CSS (bgcolor and font for example)
- put your CSS style **inline**

Be aware that some e-mail clients and webmail won't allow some styling and simply ignore them.
Gmail, for example, doesn't like `backgound-color`, and will even replace your font `color` with its own !

It's a time consuming "try and error" exercice, but I managed to build templates compatible with all the main e-mail clients (Windows Mail, Outlook(s), Gmail, Thunderbird, ...)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your helpfull answer. Do you know how i can set margin right and left because it seems that windows live mail and the outlook app are ignoring it.

Comment: I know it sounds ugly, but it would probably be easier to use a table containing 3 cells instead, using first and last cells as margins...